# Why should we define initial state in angular ngrx and what is the goal

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using angular ngrx for my app, my question is why should we define initial state in reducer instead of using "?" in a date object

I mean that with ?, you can not define initial state any more.

Answer (score 0):

Initial state is mandatory because of how reducer work. It always take the current state and based on dispatched action will do a change and return a new state.

Without *initial state* the reducer will miss the "starting point" when the first action is dispatched.

Yes, you can define a all state properties as optional with `?`, and then provide an empty initial state to the reducer, but this is really dependent on your use case.